# Girl is looking at an object

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

I remember this very old riddle involving lateral thinking.

> Girl is looking at an object. 
> During the flow of the time, it is becoming thinner at one side and thicker at another.
> What is she looking at?

In addition, it has multiple solutions. Can you guess them all? I will give some hints.

1. Is today classic (and at the same time it is the most **exact** solution).
2. Is today vintage.
3. Is today medieval technology (or even possibly neolithic).

2 and 3 can be difficult because nowadays, most of young people have never seen such devices. Luckily 1 is still in use today.

---

**Edit:**

*4. Writing this, I just noticed another solution on my screen.

**Edit 2:**

As many people post very good solutions I noticed that I should be more specific:
Hint 2:

> 1 and 2 are kinds of medium. 
>  3 is a tool. 
>  4 can be a part of UI component

**Ultimate Edit:**

> I just removed unnecessary history from the question 
>  Congratulations to xhienne and FLash.

Comment: Not sure if one of the answers you are looking for is rot13(tynff), but if it is that has actually been disproved.

Comment: @lPlant I am afraid it is not.

Comment: Please see my discussion with xhienne

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since correct answers have already been given for 2 and 4, here is my proposal for 3:

> Is it a [spindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spindle_(textiles))?
>  Or a [spinning wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_wheel)?

[edit] And here is my proposal for 1:

> She is just reading a book

To sum it up:

> 1 => book
>  2 => audio cassette
>  3 => spindle
>  4 => progress bar

Comment: Bingo! Congratulations! ;)

Comment: 1 -there is still missing solution for it. user477343 was only close.

Comment: I didn't see FLash's edit made in meantime: He is very very close to solution now.

Comment: Bingo! Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks @mpasko256 Flash has an equal number of good answers and their answer for word 1 was very very close (and as valid as a book). I suggest you ask Flash to correct their answer for word 1, to add the answer for word 3 and that you accept their answer instead of mine.

Comment: Solution for 1 is crucial because sentence 'girl was **looking at** the object' is very important for this riddle. You was first. I have plans to reward FLash anyway. How many reputation is for accepted answer? I will try to grant him some bounty If I can (never did this before)

Comment: @mpasko256 Neither did I. An accepted answer gives 15 reps. Thank you for Flash, I think they really deserve it.

Answer (score 8):

I think the classic answer (I’ve never heard this one before) might be a

> Mirror?

This is because

> She herself is getting thinner in some places, and thicker in others?

Another answer might be

> An Hourglass?

Because

> The width of the sands get thinner at the top and thicker at the bottom

Another answer might be

> A Lit Candle?

Because

> It gets thinner at the top but the wax pools at the bottom

Comment: It is not a solution but very good shots at all! +1

Comment: The second answer here was my first thought; however, self-winding is another good option.

Comment: HAHA Stole it from me as I was posting lol

Comment: Close one @PerpetualJ!!

Answer (score 6):

I see some possibilities

2.

> Audio Tape or Cassette
>  [image]

1.

> A Scroll for writing?
>  [image]

4.

> Progress bar. The width of the green increases as white decreases.
>  [image]
>  Or Scroll bar?

Comment: Congratulations: Your 1 is bingo for my 2! Your 2: Somebody just said that but it is not a solution. 4: close enough but not yet

Comment: 4: After edit: Bingo!

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your edit for 1. in the meantime. You are so close with it now! Just remember the hint that it is something still in use today ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just a couple thoughts:

First:

> Sundial; a sundial casts a shadow that gets thicker over time (at certain angles).

Second:

> Candle Clock; candle clock is an obvious choice because it slowly becomes thin at the top and thicker at the bottom as the wax melts.

Answer (score 4):

I heard once that

> Glass is some kind of superfluid, so over time, as noticable in old windows, the glass falls down with gravity, so the window is thicker at the bottom than at the top.

However

> I've since heard that that isn't true, and the reason the window is thicker at the bottom in old windows is simple down to how they were made back then.

Comment: I suppose that @lPlant had it already in mind. But interesting way of thinking anyway!

Comment: @mpasko256 oh sorry, i looked through other answers to see if anyone had already said it but must have missed that comment

Answer (score 3):

Could the classic answer be

> Her own **writing** from a pencil?

Since

> At first, the pencil could have been **sharpened**, so the lines in her written letters were **thin**. Then over time, the **lead** in the pencil would have slowly become **blunt** and her letters consequently looked **thicker** and bolder. Since she might be writing from **left to right**, the left side (or page) might look thinner than the right.

Or

> She might be **sharpening** a pencil.

Since

> A **pencil** is at first just a stick of **lead** inside some **wood**, and then gets **thinner** on the side it is **sharpened** whilst having the same thickness on the other side. The other side might even have a **rubber** at the end which gets slightly **thicker** the more you **rub** with it.

If the girl was

> writing in **cursive** (which can be considered **feminine**)

then there would be some kind of "flow".

Comment: You are very close but not yet! :) It is something very similar

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> hourglass

Because

> during the flow of the time (*maybe a hint here*), the amount of sand in the upper part decreases (so the sand pile becomes "thinner"), but it increases in the lower part (becomes "thicker")

and

> it's actually very old technology, however not yet neolithic

P.S.

> The hourglass symbol can be seen on a screen as a cursor icon!

Comment: El-Guest just proposed this solution but unfortunately it is not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> the moon? Over time (say a month or longer), the moon waxes and wanes, changing it's appearance from thin to thick.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, I thought about...

> her own life, that is thiner on the future side, and thicker on the past one!

For the second one,

> the candle sounds obvious

For the third, I thinkg PerpetualJ first answer matches!